# Scroll function firing too many times when new div created dynamically - AJAX JQUERY

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am busy making a lazy loader type function that loads a new set of data when the user reaches the bottom of a certain div.

Each time it adds new content the counter then fires too many times, for some reason if two new containers are added, then it fires the counter twice, if 4 containers are added, then the counter fires 4 times and so on...

I can't seem to find where the data is being lost. Maybe someone else can help!

I have also attached a link to the JSON data file if needed. Please let me know if you need anything more!

CODE -

```js
//AJAX FUNCTIONS

var imgTitle;
var imgLink;
var url = 'http://www.capetownetc.com/api/get_category_posts/?slug=news&count=10&page=';
var counter = 1;

function postCards(pageNumber, cardLimit, container) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET'
        , url: url + pageNumber
        , data: {
            get_param: 'value'
        }
        , dataType: 'jsonp'
        , success: function postPop(data) {
            $('.swiper-slide').append('<div class="card-container' + container + '"></div>');
            $.each(data.posts, function(i){
                imgTitle = data.posts[i].title;
                imgLink = data.posts[i].thumbnail_images.medium.url;
                
                $('.card-container' + container).append('<div class="card card1"><img src="' + imgLink + '" class="card-img"><span><h2 class="card-heading">' + imgTitle + '</h2></span></div>');
            });

        }
        
        });
        
        $(".swiper-slide").scroll(function(){
            if($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() === $(this).outerHeight()) {
                counter = counter + 1;
                postCards(counter, 10, counter);
                console.log(counter);
            };
        });
}

postCards(counter, 10, counter);
console.log(counter);
```

```css
.swiper-slide {
 overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow: scroll;
    height: 535px;
}

/*SWIPER STYLES*/

.page-content{
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 88%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.swiper-container-h {
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide {
  background:#fff;
}
.swiper-slide span {
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  margin:20px;
  font-size:21px;
}

.swiper-pagination {
 top: 0;
    height: 55px;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet{
    opacity: 1;
    background: #c4c4c4;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active{
    background: red;
}

.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets{
    right: 5px;
    top: 2%;
}

.swiper-slide {
 overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow: scroll;
    height: 535px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            
                                <div class="swiper-slide main-slide">
                                    
                                </div>
                                
</div>
```

[JSON Data File](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=97341185821408263685)

Comment: Because each `postCards()` call adds a new `scroll` handler to `.swiper-slide` which calls `postCards()` which adds a new `scroll` handler which calls `postCards()` ...

Comment: Thank you! I feel pretty dumb! Please make this the answer!

Comment: This helped me identify the problem. Please make it an answer so I can mark correct! Thanks Andreas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `postCards` function adds a new `scroll` handler each time it is executed.
Move the `$(".swiper-slide").scroll(...)` part out of the `postCards()` function so it is only executed once.

```
function postCards(pageNumber, cardLimit, container) {
  $.ajax({
    //...
  });
}

$(".swiper-slide").scroll(function() {
  var slide = $(this);

  if (slide[0].scrollHeight - slide.scrollTop() === slide.outerHeight()) {
    counter = counter + 1;
    postCards(counter, 10, counter);
    console.log(counter);
  };
});
```